# How to write such complex relations in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

if there is a table of r (c,s) and such relations (c means class, s means students), I want to know all possible combination of c1, c2, ..c5, s1,...s8 , How to write the SQL clause? I tried to write it using case when, but it's too slow. I'm using PostgreSQl.

```
c1:s1,s5,s7
c2:s1,s2,s3,s4
c3:s2,s6,s8
c4:s4,s5,s6
c5:s3,s7,s8
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Normalize your database and you won't have problems like this.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make array\_agg() work like group\_concat() from mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054559/how-to-make-array-agg-work-like-group-concat-from-mysql)

Comment: no, this is different from the post of array_agg(). In my case, I know the relations of (c1:s1,s5,s7 ...) and all data of r (c,s). I want to figure out all possible combinations of c1,c2...s1,s2..s8. This is reverse application to the post of array_agg(). In my example, I need to use a serial of predicates under WHERE to represent the (c1:s1,s5,s7 ..) relation , but do not know how to.

Comment: Are you looking for cross join maybe?

Comment: even for CROSS JOIN, it's also hard to use SQL to represent such a relation....do you have some idea? @Mihai

Comment: Create a representative fiddle.

Comment: It's hard because you are storing comma separated values, i.e. lists of students and not students in the `s` column.

Comment: Could you please say more about fiddle? I don't quite understand it ...@Mihai

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: If you post the `CASE` `WHEN` query that was too slow, that will help us figure out exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c, string_agg(s, ',')
FROM r
GROUP BY c;
```

Note: `string_agg()` was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.0.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my problem, please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to exchange the rows to table r(c,s) columns?
If you want, You can use This SQL for exp :

```
digoal=# select split_part(val,':',1), regexp_split_to_table(split_part(val,':',2), ',') from (values ('c1:s1,s5,s7'),('c2:s1,s2,s3,s4')) as t(val);
 split_part | regexp_split_to_table 
------------+-----------------------
 c1         | s1
 c1         | s5
 c1         | s7
 c2         | s1
 c2         | s2
 c2         | s3
 c2         | s4
(7 rows)
```